# How do I run ffmpeg with PHP on a Mac with XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, apache, ffmpeg, xampp

There is literally nothing on this anywhere, the little there is does not work and is too advanced for me. If you can answer this you would make my life. How do I run ffmpeg commands from php which is running on my localhost? I prefer XAMPP, but MAMP will do just fine, at this stage I will use anything. Do I need to install ffmpeg on the XAMPP server itself, or does it just need to be installed on the mac? I can run the ffmpeg commands fine from terminal, for example,

```
ffmpeg -i Tmpfile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast video.mp4
```

works fine, but

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i Tmpfile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast video.mp4");
```

does nothing when I load the webpage with the index.php that that code is in.

I will buy you a cookie if you can solve my problem :)

Comment: What does your PHP error log show?

Comment: The path to your files are correct? Are they in the same directory as your PHP script?

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4/bin/ffmpeg' is the path of the homebrew installed ffmpeg file. There is only one file, unlike the windows xampp tutorials where there are many files. The file opens a terminal window when clicked. That path is what I link to in my php script. I save it as a $ffmpeg variable and then echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i Tmpfile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast video.mp4"); to try and run it. I will try using it in the same directory as the script itself.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard here is one error message when I try linking to the path where ffmpeg is located on my system (not xampp): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libJPEG.dylib in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO

Comment: Error when just trying to shell exec the ffmpeg command without the path (including the file in the same dir as the php script), is ffmpeg: command not found

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific when describing the problem, e.g. including OSX version, ffmpeg version, etc.

I successfully managed to reproduce your case, here it is the procedure:

## 1. ffmpeg

I installed `ffmpeg` via [brew](https://brew.sh). ffmpeg version is currently 3.2.4.

## 2. PHP server

On macOS Sierra (but other previous versions offer this feature as well), you can start a PHP server by just typing

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

in your shell. The web server will listen on port 8080 in that case.

## 3. The PHP script

I basically used the script you gave in your question, with a little modification:

```
<?php

echo "loading, please wait...";

echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast video.mp4 2>&1");
```

Did you notice the `2>&1`? It is used to redirect the `sterr` output to the `stdoutput` as ffmpeg would not print anything on standard output :)

## 4. Safe mode?

Please be sure to disable PHP safe mode, as the `shell_exec` method is disabled when safe mode is ON ([reference here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#refsect1-function.shell-exec-notes)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still haven't really solved the problem though. I am using the very latest version of everything(sierra, ffmpeg 3.2.4). I tried your way, and it works! But - my problem is getting it to work on XAMPP or MAMP (apache server). I do not know where to place the files in the xampp directory. Should I be linking to the unix executable file from the script (the one downloaded from their website, or stored in /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4/bin/ffmpeg' when installing from brew)?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have found the answer. I needed to add this to the beginning of the php script

```
    exec('unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin');
```

Comment: I am no PHP expert - but I would imagine that just the last line above will be sufficient, without the first two lines.